# svg pattern on background image

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Is it possible to put a .svg pattern as a background image, the svg pattern should be resized to the window width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but limited in browser support. Webkit tends to have the best SVG support and IE the worst. You can assign it using CSS and the CSS3 [background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property.

```
body {
  background: url(bg.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
}
```

You can wrangle a bit more support by putting the SVG in an `<img>` and absolutely positioning and stretching it behind your content. This works because IE historically has more support for SVG as an `<img>` or `<object>` than as a CSS resource.

Comment: Are you kidding webkit has best svg support? [Nobody has beaten opera yet](http://codedread.com/svg-support.php) . 

And concerning your css, opera doesn'n need -o- prefix for background-size, and the prefixless statement has to be placed after all the prefixed ones.